# Mensa IQ Check app puzzle - symbols in boxes in a 6x6 square

Tags: pattern, visual, symbols

In the Mensa IQ Check app, the same kind of puzzles keeps coming back. I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: @ Jan        I am still waiting for your response.

Comment: @ Jan.   Are you checking  the answers to  your question?

Answer (score 40):

Answer

> X

Because

> The pattern needs the X to repeat
>  There is a pattern of 5 possible symbols: X # O @ !.  
>  The pattern repeats in a spiral pattern around the square (Starting at the left top corner).
>  [image]

Comment: What does "the pattern needs the X to repeat" mean? What does the picture show? Please explain more.

Comment: @bobble, edited for clarity.

Comment: I see it now, thanks!

Comment: Took me about 25 seconds. +1

Comment: @Tim, that's pretty quick.  It took me a bit longer than that.  lol.

Answer (score 1):

> O

Because

> When you draw the bottom-left top-right extended diagonals, there are duplicate symbols sitting next to each other on every line

> [image: Bottom-left top-right diagonal]

(I think MacGyver88's solution is simpler, so it is probably what the author thought about).

Answer (score 0):

From the six columns only the fourth contains the same symbol 3 times, namely the symbol $O$. In addition to that, none of the rows contains the same symbol 3 times. If we replace the question mark which is on fourth row with the symbol $X$ then on the fourth row the symbol $X$ appears 3 times as well.

Answer (score -1):

Or....

> Each row has exactly one symbol duplicated. In the ? row the X is already duplicated, meaning the answer must be #, to have all 5 symbols.

Comment: This fails in the third row, where both O and @ are duplicated, or the 5th with ! and #